# Ansible : remote_user in playbook file issues

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Actually I've defined remote_user variable for each host group. But remote_user value is not taken from defined one. Rather its using top assigned value.

Ansible version:

```
# ansible --version
ansible 2.3.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Playbook file : info.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: demo 
  roles:
  - common

- hosts: devlocal
  remote_user: root
  become: yes
  roles:
  - common

- hosts: testlocal
  remote_user: test
  become: yes
  roles:
  - common
```

when I run the playbook for hosts [ devlocal]  , the users name is taken from first assignment [ i.e : "demo" ]. Actually it should use the remote_user "root" in my case.

logs :

```
# ansible-playbook  -i hosts -l devlocal info.yml  --ask-pass -vvvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password: 
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc

PLAYBOOK: site.yml ********************************************************************************************************************************
3 plays in site.yml

PLAY [all] ****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<10.11.12.213> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: demo
```

Someone please help what was an issue here. Thanks in advance

Comment: why the question was downgraded. any reasons ?

Answer (score 0):

> Someone please help what was an issue here.

The issue here is that you specified the first play to run as `demo`:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: demo 
  roles:
  - common
```

And Ansible runs it as `demo` which seems not to be your objective.

That's why Ansible provides [inventory mechanism](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html), so you can specify connection details per host, not in plays.

Answer (score 0):

> I've defined remote_user variable for each host group

Wrong. You've defined `remote_user` for each play and not host group.
Hosts and groups are defined via inventory.
So you should defined `devlocal` and `testlocal` groups with `ansible_user` assigned.

And have single play:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
  - common
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I created that playbook with reference from the ansible examples "https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/lamp_simple_rhel7/site.yml". Is that way not a correct one ?.

Comment: The linked examples shows how you should apply different roles to different host groups under same user account.

Comment: can't we create/run it for "different user account" ?. For that, I should create separate playbook for this ?. One more doubt, can't we set remote_port in the playbook file "remote_port=22022" ?.

Comment: please take a look at inventories via @techraf's link – it's essential topic to understand how Ansible works.